# Forwarding port to Node.js app with Nginx and routing

Tags: node.js, nginx, routes

I run my node app on `localhost:3000` and it is serving a default page for the route `/`. If I access `http://localhost:3000` the default page is displayed accordingly. I have also running a Nginx server that is basically configured as followed:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /node_app {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

If I run `http://localhost/node_app` now, my node app throws an error saying that it cannot find route `/node_app`.

**How can I configure either my node app or the nginx server in a way that I can access the app by calling `http://localhost/node_app`, yet the app itself thinks it is at `/`?**

### Update

If I add a `/` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` it is actually matching `/node_app` to the `/` route. But now every stylesheet for instance within the default page is now pointing to the wrong path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After experimenting a bit around I finally got the configuration right to work exactly how I wanted the server to work:

```
server {
    location /node_app/ {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**Lesson learned: Remember the slashes!**

Comment: Did not work for me. am still getting the react app error :/

Comment: i did what you explained and i can see the login page but all my sigin and signup functions aren't working